# how to when search a username then show only one pagination line?

Tags: php, pagination

Heys guys I am beginner in programming field so I have no much experience. I have record of users. when I am search a name of user in search box then only one pagination line showing me that is ok check this [link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJp8F.png)

But when I am remove name of user in search box then one more pagination line showing that I dont want it. I want only one pagination line when search a name of user and remove a name of user check this [link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQMGD.png)

Thanks in advance

**This is my code**

```
<script>
    function deleteConfirm(){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure to delete users?");
    if(result){
    return true;
    } else
      {
       return false;
    }
    }

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
     if(this.checked){
     $('.checkbox').each(function(){
        this.checked = true;
        });
    }else{
         $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
  });

$('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
    if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
    }
}); 
});
  </script>
  <?php

     include("common/config.php");
     $output = '';

 if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
  $search =  $_POST["query"];


  $where = "id LIKE '%".$search."%'
       OR name LIKE '%".$search."%'
       OR email LIKE '%".$search."%'
       OR phone LIKE '%".$search."%' ";

 $query = $db->select(array("*"),"user","$where","","id desc","");


 }
  else
{
   $limit = 5; 

$page = '';
if (isset($_GET["page"] )) 
    {
    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } 
else 
   {
    $page=1; 
   } 

  $record_index= ($page-1) * $limit; 

   $query = $db->select(array("*"),PREFIX."user", "", "", "id desc", "$record_index, $limit");
   }

if($query)
{

   $output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <form name="bulk_action_form" action="action.php" onSubmit="return 
   deleteConfirm();"/>
    <table id="result" class="table table bordered">
<tr>
 <th style="text-align: center !important;"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>
 <th style="text-align: center !important;">ID</th>
 <th style="text-align: center !important;">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center !important;">Email</th>
    <th style="text-align: center !important;">Phone</th>
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center !important;">Action</th>
</tr>';

foreach($query as $row)

 {
   $output .= '
   <tr align="center">
     <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  name="checked_id[]"  
        class="checkbox" value="'.$row->id.'"/></td> 
     <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
     <td><a href="edit-form.php?edit='.$row->id.'">Edit</a></td>
     <td><a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="del.php?del='.$row->id.'">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>';
 }

  $output .= '</form></table><br /><div align="center">';  
  $total_pages = ceil($db->countfields("*","user") / $limit);  
    for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
 {  
    $output .= "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";  
 }

    $output .= '</div><br /><br />';  
   echo $output;
 }

 else
 {
  echo 'Data Not Found';
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the second image that is wrong. The first one only has 1 result but still has 4 pages.

It seems that you have some static div with 4 pages in your html. This is probably some html from below the php code that you posted and that you forgot to delete.

From what you posted its the only explanation. If it's not that could you post the rest of the html code?

Comment: User records are showing from this page. Not other html code is written.

Comment: There must be more. There are other things in the images you posted that are not in the code you posted. Like that pagination input and the last delete button. That extra pagination div is most likely right before that input.